# Ansible: How to parse string to evaluate jinja expressions during set_fact

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a string containing a jinja expression. How can I parse/evaluate/expand/ that string so that the expression is replaced the host variable running the role/task?

### Detailed explanation:

I do have a proxmox cluster with multiple hosts. I want to manage their iptables with a dedicated role, but with separate data sources. The role should collect all variables that start with a specific prefix, collect their rules for filter and nat tables, sort them and write them into `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`via `ansible.builtin.template`.
Later I want to define multiple lxc/ and VMs inside group_vars, e.g. `inventory/group_vars/proxmox/lxc_nginx.yml`: ```

```yaml
nginx_reverse_proxy:
  host: '<some_cluster_node>'
  network:
    ip: 10.1.0.3
    cidr: 24

iprules_nginx_reverse_proxy:
    nat:
      weight: 20
      entries: |
        -A PREROUTING -i {{ network_external_ip.external_device }} -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.0.3
```

with `network_external_ip` beeing defined for each node, in `inventory/host_vars/some_cluster_node.yml`:

```yaml
network_external_ip:
  ip: 1.1.1.1
  gateway: 0.0.0.0
  mask: 255.255.252.0
  cidr: 22
  external_device: ens3 # <<< this differs for each cluster node
```

now I collect all iprules, which might have been defined in multiple files, within my role and try to get them all converted into a sorted dict:

```yaml
- name: basics/iptables | collect all rules
  set_fact:
    helper: |
      {%- set filter = [] %}
      {%- set nat = [] %}
      {%- for entry in vars.items() %}
      {%-   if entry[0].startswith('iprules_') %}
      {%-     if entry[1].filter is defined %}
      {%-       set _ = filter.append(entry[1].filter) %}
      {%-     endif %}
      {%-     if entry[1].nat is defined %}
      {%-       set _ = nat.append(entry[1].nat) %}
      {%-     endif %}
      {%-   endif %}
      {%- endfor %}
      {%- set filter = filter | sort(attribute='weight') | map(attribute='entries') | join('\\n')  %}
      {%- set nat = nat | sort(attribute='weight') | map(attribute='entries') | join('\\n') -%}
      filter: "{{ filter }}"
      nat: "{{ nat }}"

- name: basics/iptables | create iptables dict
  set_fact:
    iptables_rules: "{{ helper | from_yaml }}"

- name: debug
  debug:
    var: iptables_rules

- name: basics/iptables | write ip rules
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: rules.v4.j2
    dest: /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

which results in:

```
TASK [basics/iptables : basics/iptables | collect all rules] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [<some_cluster_node>]

TASK [basics/iptables : basics/iptables | create iptables dict] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [<some_cluster_node>]

TASK [basics/iptables : debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [<some_cluster_node>] => 
  iptables_rules:
    filter: ''
    nat: '-A PREROUTING -i {{ network_external_ip.external_device }} -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.0.3 '
```

Meaning, `{{ network_external_ip.external_device }}` never gets evaluated to "ens3". It stays the same, as in the inventory. How can I get this expression being parsed?

Information: The shown dicts here are WIP and do not fulfill certain criteria (like I would write all iprules_* into all hosts, regardless if they even host the lxc), but without the basics working this is no a concern right now.

PS: ansible version used

```
~ $ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.13.5]
  config file = /home/apit/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/apit/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/apit/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/lib/python-exec/python3.10/ansible
  python version = 3.10.8 (main, Nov 27 2022, 20:55:16) [GCC 11.3.0]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

Comment: At least using the latest ansible version, [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/8b96c35c1664cd572c9f9670a4dc61cc)

Comment: I added my ansible version to the description

Comment: I updated to ansible 6.6.0 and still get the same result

Comment: Please provide a [mre], i.e. a complete file structure, a minimal but complete playbook and the command used (as I did in the above link) to reproduce the problem.